# Managing wide genomics data in parquet

Tags: parquet, delta-lake, pyarrow

My genomics dataset has the shape of a very large number (think millions) of rows and 250k+ columns.

I'd like to optimize retrieving a subset of columns and a subset of rows to scan the least amount of data. Of course, I want to do this as fast as possible as well. Additionally, I need to be able to append new rows a couple of times a week. Annually, I need to append new columns. On rare exceptions, I need to be able to update existing rows and columns.

Example use cases:

- Query all columns for M rows
- Query all rows for N columns
- Query M rows with N columns
- Aggregate on N columns across all rows (e.g. count N columns grouped by values)

Each cell value is a string type, e.g. 'AT', 'CG'.

I'm new to managing data this wide in parquet so I'm seeking advice on whether one of the below attempts is one that I should pursue further or whether there is a better path to explore altogether.

I've tried the following:

- All columns - This appeared to work on write/read, but managing the schema appears to be tricky to integrate into SQL engines. For example, AWS Glue could not crawl my parquet files to populate tables in AWS Athena.
- Split dataset using the datasets API by column groups - This seems viable, but I'm not sure how I would manage updates and appends to the dataset. For example, how would I append a new row to the dataset?
- Don't store as columns. Instead, I stored the transposed version of the data. The data size bloated due to redundant data, but all of the tools played well with the long format over the wide format.

I've tried the above variations in Delta Lake + Spark and PyArrow + Parquet. Both have similar issues.

What's the best (cheapest and most performant) way to store and access this data?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting dataset. I wonder about the very large number of columns, are they all non-empty? If not, is there a specific pattern to the sparsity? I am thinking of a solution that would be along the lines of column groups (like you wrote), with some hard-coded column splitting into groups...

Comment: Unfortunately, they are typically not sparse with a high level of missing values indicating a bad genotyping process (i.e. something went wrong at the lab)

Comment: I'm on Azure not AWS so maybe it works differently but can't you copy your files to S3 buckets then query them from Athena and bypass their Glue service?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Delta Lake with Spark for storing your dataset:

- Delta Tables support schema evolution unlike plain parquet, this will allow you to add columns as needed without rewriting the entire dataset.
- For improving query performance, I'd suggest reducing the number of
  files you need to scan by partitioning your dataset by
  chromosome/contig.
- If you are storing many continuous values alongside your reads, e.g. quality scores, you may benefit from
  Z-Ordering your data. Performance optimizations for Delta Lake can be
  found in the [docs
  here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html).

The other benefit of this approach is you're not *actually* breaking your data up across different stores that you need to query against and manage separately. You can query against the entire table (and all underlying files) as a single pool of data, and spark + Delta Lake optimizations make it performant. If you have VCF data in addition to your reads, consider [project glow](https://glow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) alongside Spark + Delta Lake.